# Perfectly scaling background that only appears after a certain time and allows background colour beforehand

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm new to Webdev in general and things were going pretty smooth in self study until I hit a slight snag on this one problem I've been having.

For one page on my website, I'm using frames (not iframes, just frames... I realize they're awful I'm just trying to use them for a specific purpose here) and I want an image to scale up completely to fill one frame's height, not just stopping when it fills width. That's already a problem I've seen a few people have, and there is a simple solution I kind of retrofitted onto my code from the people at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) (I expanded the shortform to make it easier for me to understand):

```
body { 
      background-image: url('/aboutme/fractal.gif');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

[And that seems to do the trick just fine!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlJJO.png) But my problem comes from something more specific: I want the image to show up later on, and have there be no background image to start- just a background colour. I also use code to change the background colour every so often before changing to the image. The problem is that I can't figure out for the life of me how to either change the style to work with background colours or to change the background image set setting to work with the html styling. Everything I've tried has resulted in either a blank screen or incorrect input/timing.

My "set image" code, which is what I used before trying out this new code, and it worked only it set just the width to fill:

```
function toEuphoria() {
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = url('/aboutme/fractal.gif');
}
```

In short: I am trying to set an image to fill up both width and height, but have it only appear later- and have coloured backgrounds appear beforehand. Sorry if I'm not totally clear, it's really late. Any help at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a background 'color' and 'image' to any element simultaneously, just take that in to account in your javascript;

```
body{
  background:      #2c2d2e url('/aboutme/fractal.gif');
  background-size: cover;
}

function toEuphoria() {
   document.body.style.background = "transparent url('/aboutme/fractal.gif')";
   document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
}
```

Your background-size will be preserved when you swap from a background-color to a background-image and vis-versa.

EDIT

---

A js fiddle with randomly changing background (color, image, color) that demonstrates the above. https://jsfiddle.net/u5x87q6y/1/